Task.Run() not working on Azure App Service but fine locally
I'm in the process of updating a web app from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET 6. There's a chunk of code that uses Task.Run() to do some fire and forget bits (user clicks a button on a web page that builds and runs a long-running PowerShell script on a VM). The code works fine locally - I've logged plenty of messages throughout the processes involved, but does not run when I deploy it to an Azure app service.
I've pulled the code to bits as there were some significant changes with regards to controlling VMs between the versions of .NET to make sure it's not related to that. On the app service, Application Insights logs up to the point of the Task.Run line but then nothing after that and I've not found anywhere in the Azure portal that gives me a clue as to what the issue might be.
I've got the code now to a point where I'm pretty certain it's Task.Run that's the issue as my code just does a loop, logging as it goes. Locally, this logs to Application Insights as expected.
The code also works fine if I just call it without Task.Run() but I'm thinking I need to keep using a Task (I wasn't involved in the original implementation) if possible, due to the long-running nature of the task.
Short question is - what would stop a very simple Task.Run() from executing from within an App Service when the code works fine locally?
Edited to add code...
Code called from web page - identifies a VM to run the code on but here we just call RunTestTask:
public IActionResult GenerateUsingTask(pageViewModel vm, string id)
    {
        var virtualMachine = _configService.GetVm(id);
        if (virtualMachine == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        
        _configService.SwitchOn(virtualMachine, User.Identity.Name, vm.Static).Wait();
        _logger.LogInformation("Going into RunTestTask");

        Task.Run(()=>_configService.RunTestTask(virtualMachine,User.Identity.Name));
        _logger.LogInformation("After RunTestTask");
        
        return Ok();
    }

RunTestTask just looks like this:
public void RunTestTask(theVm vm, string user)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Into test task");

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i % 10 == 0) { 
                    _logger.LogInformation("Logging " + i);
                }
            }
            _logger.LogInformation("Out of test task");
        }

When running locally I see all of the logging in both chunks of code. When deployed to Azure, the logging in Application Insights stops at the "Going into RunTestTask" line (see image links)
Local ApplicationInsights
Application insights when running in VS 2022 locally
Deployed ApplicationInsights
Application insights from deployed App service
2nd edit to add more representative code :
public IActionResult Generate(PageViewModel vm, string id)
    {
   
        var virtualMachine = _configService.GetVm(id);
        if (virtualMachine == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        
        _configService.SwitchOn(virtualMachine, User.Identity.Name, vm.Static).Wait();
        _logger.LogInformation("Going into RunScripts");

        try
        {
            Task.Run(()=>_configService.RunScripts(virtualMachine, User.Identity.Name, vm.Static, vm.Pending));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical("Error in Generate - message" + ex.Message);
            _logger.LogCritical("Error in Generate - stacktrace" + ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }

        return Ok();
    }

RunScripts looks like this
public void RunScripts(ScriptingVm vm, string user, bool moduleDataSets, bool edits)
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var outputFolder = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Scripts_OUTPUT_FOLDER");

        _logger.LogInformation("Environment is " + env);

        //simple powershell test
        //string sDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss");
        //_logger.LogCritical("Want to create folder on " + vm.Id + " - " + sDate);
        //string folderName = "C:\\temp\\Test_" + sDate;
        //var result = _vmService.RunPowerShellScript(vm.Id,
        //    new List<string> { "param([string]$folderName) New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $folderName" }, new List<RunCommandInputParameter>() { new RunCommandInputParameter("folderName", folderName) });
        //simple powershell test

        _logger.LogInformation("server :: " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Scripts_SERVER"));
        _logger.LogInformation("username :: " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Scripts_DB_USER"));
        //...logs more environment variables...
        try
        {
            var result = _vmService.RunPowerShellScript(vm.Id, new List<string>
            {
                "param(",
                "    [string]$server,",
                "    [string]$login,",
                //...more variables here...
                ")",
                $@"Set-Location {outputFolder}",
                @"& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' pull $gitCredential",
                @"& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' checkout $sourceBranch",
                @"& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' checkout -B $branch"
            }.Concat((moduleDataSets ? DeleteFolders.Concat(ModuleDataSetDeleteFolders) : DeleteFolders)
                .Select(f => $"Remove-Item -path \"Config\\{f}\" -recurse")
                ).Concat(new List<string> {
                @"& 'C:\Python\Python36\python.exe' scripts\configscripts\master.py " + (moduleDataSets ? "-m " : "") + "-o $output -l $login -s $server, " +
                    "-d $database -u $username -p $password -n $clientName -a $clientSecret -t $tenant -r $url",
                @"& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' config user.email $gitEmail",
                @"& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' config user.name $gitUser",
                @"& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' add -A",
                @"& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' commit -m $commitMsg",
                @"& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' push $remote $branch --force",
                @"& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' checkout $sourceBranch",
            }).ToList(),
            new List<RunCommandInputParameter>
            {
                new RunCommandInputParameter("server", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Scripts_SERVER")),
                new RunCommandInputParameter("username", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Scripts_DB_USER")),
                //...more variables here...
            });

            if (result.HasValue)
            {
                //what to report to user
                string loopOutput = "";

                foreach (var s in result.Value.Value)
                {
                    loopOutput += s.Message + "/n";

                }
                _logger.LogInformation(loopOutput);

                //reported to user via database
                var report = new ScriptingReport
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now,
                    User = user,
                    Report = loopOutput
                };
                _repository.Create(report);

                vm.LastReportId = report.Id;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical($"Error: {ex.Message}");

            var report = new ScriptingReport
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                User = user,
                Report = ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace.ToString()
            };
            _repository.Create(report);
            vm.LastReportId = report.Id;
        }
        finally
        {
            //vm object has been updated with newly inserted LastReportId value to link vm to results

            SwitchOff(vm);
        }
    }

RunPowerShellScript is as follows:
public ArmOperation<VirtualMachineRunCommandResult> RunPowerShellScript(string virtualMachineName, List<string> commands, List<RunCommandInputParameter> parameters)
    {
        
        //used to be a single line (.Net Core 2)
        //return _azure.VirtualMachines.RunPowerShellScript(ResourceGroupName, virtualMachineName, commands, parameters);
        SubscriptionResource subsRes = _armClient.GetDefaultSubscription();
        ResourceGroupResource resGroup = subsRes.GetResourceGroup(ResourceGroupName);
        VirtualMachineCollection vmColl = resGroup.GetVirtualMachines();

        if (vmColl.Exists(virtualMachineName))
        {
            VirtualMachineResource vmR = vmColl.Get(virtualMachineName);
            RunCommandInput runCommInput = new RunCommandInput("RunPowerShellScript");

            //Script is readonly so can't directly pass in
            //pass in command
            string commandsString = "";
            foreach (var command in commands)
            {
                runCommInput.Script.Add(command);
                commandsString += command + ": " + "\n";

            }
            
            _logger.LogInformation(string.Format("Command list: {0}", commandsString));

            //pass in commmand parameters
            string paramsString = "";
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                runCommInput.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                paramsString += parameter.Name + ": " + parameter.Value.ToString() + "\n";
            }
            _logger.LogInformation(string.Format("Parameter list: {0}", paramsString));

            var res = vmR.RunCommand(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, runCommInput);
            return res;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        };
    }


Hi and welcome to SO. Questions about code should include the actual code, or at least a very representative subset of it. Please [edit] the question and add the code.

"what would stop a very simple Task.Run() from executing from within an App Service" - perhaps the request is finishing and the injected dependencies are being discarded before the task is complete. Doesn't seem that the structure you have is ideal for this sort of work. Better you have some queueing system where jobs are queued and a worker processes them after the fact, or even just using some background job runner (Hangfire) or awaiting the task and triggering it from something patient, like a logic app if you need scheduling of it

Thanks for the welcome and the advice to put some code in. Edits have been made as suggested.

@flackoverstow - this task is a very simple test one. My previous iteration involved a simple Powershell script to create a timestamped folder on the VM in question to ascertain whether I had the VM / PowerShell syntax correct. Same pattern of working locally but no evidence of the task running and creating the folder when running from a deployed app service. If the Task was running at all I would have expected to see a folder being created, even if the logging wasn't being done. Agree with your points about the structure...

Issue the first:
_configService.SwitchOn(virtualMachine, User.Identity.Name, vm.Static).Wait();

Async over sync

There are very few ways to use Task.Result and Task.Wait correctly so the general advice is to completely avoid using them in your code.

This is not one of the few ways to use .Wait() correctly.
Resolution: Make your GenerateUsingTask() method async and use await.
await _configService.SwitchOn(virtualMachine, User.Identity.Name, vm.Static);

Issue the second

Use Task.Run() for CPU bound operations only. REF: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html

You said you were waiting for a PowerShell script to run and logging to app insights. Those are I/O bound operations, and you should not be using Task.Run().

'Fire and forget' I would argue is not ubiquitous C#. But don't take only  my word for it.

Suggestions:
We need more context. You said the purpose of the bit of code in Task.Run() was to build and execute a PowerShell script, but the bit your shared was a loop that logged to app insights.
Conclusion:

This has nothing to do with Azure App Service. This is a symptom of "works on my machine".  Fix the code, and the problem will go away for all machines.
Make your method async.
Don't use Task.Run() for I/O bound operations.  If this is a truly fire and forget, send a message to something that builds the PS script, then send a message to something that executes the PS script. (guessing at requirements).

If you make your question more clear, I'll try and make my answer more clear.
Edit:
I spy an existing bug / known issue with Azure.WaitUntil.Completed:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/42040
var res = vmR.RunCommand(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, runCommInput);

I don't have a solution for this in your existing code. Sorry, this may need to be a separate StackOverflow question to address this problem.

Thanks for the advice re the first issue @Adam - another edit made to original question to add more representative code.

@Pete see edit: You may be running into a bug with Azure.WaitUnit.Complete  I'm not familiar with this, and you may have better luck if you can isolate this.  I would also recommend a separate SO question tagging the azure-sdk team.

thanks for the info I will take a look and then see if I need to ask a separate question of the azure-sdk-team.
